# Android device can't boot

Tags: boot

I have this device Samsung A5 2016 which has not booted for a while, wanting to repair it, I went into recovery mode however no option seemed to work, recurring error which appeared: "can't find misc/", I tried to make a bootable SD card then to execute it from recovery mode, error "can't find sdcard/".

I also tried to go through Odin mode, however the device does not have USB debugging active it is not in the list of devices connected to adb, so I can do nothing on this side there.

What do you recommend ?

Comment: flash tools doesn't rely on usb-debugging, enter download mode with proper key combo and install drivers

Comment: @alecxs Can you please expand on what you said?

Comment: sorry maybe my english is not the best. Odin3 requires usb drivers installed while phone connected in download mode. but requires no adb/usb-debugging at all. download mode can be activated with combination of power + home + vol down buttons